How do I create a restricted postgres role for a text-2-sql app?
I'm using AGI to generate Postgres SQL (AWS RDS Postgres) but I want to prevent users asking questions about underlying tables such as "Show me all databases", "Show me all users" that result in queries like SELECT * FROM pg_database and SELECT * FROM pg_roles.
The working script I have for this is:
Connect to postgres as postgres (super user):
CREATE ROLE client_creator WITH LOGIN PASSWORD '<generate>' CREATEDB CREATEROLE;

Connect to postgres as client_creator:
CREATE DATABASE "client_db";
CREATE ROLE "client_reader" WITH LOGIN PASSWORD '<generate>';

Connect to client_db as client_creator
GRANT CONNECT, TEMPORARY ON DATABASE "client_db" TO "client_reader";
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO "client_reader";
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO "client_reader";

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO "client_reader"; 

REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA pg_catalog FROM client_reader;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA pg_catalog FROM public;

The issue is the final two REVOKE commands seem to have no effect since I can still run SELECT * FROM pg_roles and receive all rows.
I've also tried revoking SELECT on tables in the pg_catalog too.
Question is:

Can I do this?
Should I do this? Thoughts...

I have seen comments in other posts that suggest this is a bad idea but since I understand each database has a copy of pg_catalog I thought it would not be an issue
I believe the generate queries should not rely on pg_catalog objects but I may be wrong




You must be a superuser to mess with the privileges on the system schema pg_catalog; a normal user won't be able to do that. Removing the USAGE privilege on schema pg_catalog from PUBLIC will restrict access for normal users, but not for superusers, who are exempt from privilege restrictions.
Doing that is a bad idea, because it will break all interactive clients and may cause other, worse, problems. Metadata are public in PostgreSQL, and you shouldn't try to change that (see the many other questions about that topic). The only reasonable way to prevent a user from seeing others' metadata is to put them into different databases, since every database has its own catalog tables.

By "put them into different databases", do you mean separate database instance/cluster? Using the same cluster, I have separate databases but it seems pg_database shows all in the cluster.

Also "Superusers are not subject to restrictions from privileges". I was authenticated as client_reader when testing SELECT * FROM pg_database; which is not a superuser right, unless I misunderstand?!

Ah, yes. But only a superusers can change the permissions on pg_catalog.
